# How to require and export icons so that I can dynamically import using a string value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a string that is the name of the icon I want to import/require and I'm trying to import/require the SVG file that I want to use in React Native dynamically. My initial idea was this:

```
const icon = require(`@src/assets/icons/${iconName}`)
```

However, I realized that this would not work and that I need to have all my icon options imported. This is why I created an `Icons.ts` file from which I'm trying to require and then export all my icons like this:

```
const Icons = {
    ArrowRight: import('@src/assets/icons/ArrowRight.svg'),
    ArrowLeft: import('@src/assets/icons/ArrowLeft.svg'),
};

export default Icons;
```

And then I attempted to use them in my component like by hardcoding Icons.ArrowRight:

```
{leftIcon && <IconContainer>{Icons.ArrowRight}</IconContainer>}
```

Which unfortunately didn't work and I got the following error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child.
```

If I import an icon straight in my component like this:

```
import Close from '@src/assets/icons/close.svg';
```

I can then use it like this:

```
<Close />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the icon component.

```
<IconContainer><Icons.ArrowRight /></IconContainer>}
```